# Join two tables using a condition on time, sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join two tables, but the issue is that as a condition i need their field "time" to be approximately the same.

Let me write a little clearer, this is what i thought to do up to now.

```
SELECT location
FROM retailer
LEFT JOIN imovo
ON retailer.time=imovo.time.
```

Now, what i really need is not this :  retailer.time=imovo.time but i need that the difference between the seconds of the field in retailer table to be not larger than 4 seconds to the imovo time field.

Let me explain, let's suppose the time field from retailer says: 11:11:23 i should join this two tables if the time from imovo is between : 11:11:23 and 11:11:26

So, could you please help me on this one?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
ON addtime(retailer.time, '0:0:4')<imovo.time
AND retailer.time >imovo.time
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work:

```
imovo.time between retailer.time and retailer.time + interval 4 second
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer :)
I'll test it, but it seems to be reasonable enough!
Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

make a join on hour and minute and add a where clause as

pseudo code
where (imovo.time - retailer.time) < 4 second

Comment: Thanks, now, would i have to do it by setting hour/minute/seconds in different fields or can it be done if you put them together?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do as an earlier poster suggested, and join on hour and minute you could try the built-in HOUR and MINUTE functions. See:

References & useful pages:

- ["MySQL :: MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 12.7 Date and Time Functions -- Hour"  [dev.mysql.com]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour)
- ["MySQL :: MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 12.7 Date and Time Functions -- Minute"  [dev.mysql.com]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute)
- [Google Search: 'mysql date time get seconds'](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=mysql+date+time+get+seconds&oq=mysql+date+time+get+seconds&gs_l=hp.3...2524.7934.0.8533.27.27.0.0.0.0.111.1400.26j1.27.0.efrsh..0.0...1.60PyV0RCpGk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=c8555e532373c719&biw=1680&bih=972)

[[CiteHistory Record](http://bit.ly/Of1GMV)]

Answer (score 0):

I think MySQL does not support INTERVAL (could not quickly find it in the manuals), if ti does, mix @grossvogel's answer with the +/- 4 to get your margin working on both sides.

```
SELECT location
FROM retailer
LEFT JOIN imovo
ON TO_SECONDS(imovo.time) BETWEEN TO_SECONDS(retailer.time) - 4 AND TO_SECONDS(retailer.time) + 4
```

Comment: Read down just a bit from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add and you'll see the `interval` notation.

Comment: Cool! I looked in the literal value section of the manual and couldn't find it. Odd that INTERVAL is not supported as a data type, which is where I was looking.